# Telerik MVC Grid Control Additional Column with ActionLink

Tags: grid, telerik, actionlink

Hi I am Using Telerik MVC Grid Control in my MVC 3.0 Project

I am trying to add Additional Column to the Grid

```
  columns.Template(e =>
         @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Action", "Controller",
         new { id = e.ID}, new { @class = "standard button" })
           );
```

This code is Creating an Additional Column  But not displaying the Edit link in that column.

Can Any one Help me with this. How can make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you come from a WebForms (ASPX) ViewEngine world it can be a little confusing when working with column templates as traditionally you used to have to do `columns.Template(e => .... );`. However, with Razor we can now approach this a little differently. First of all, the usage of @ is embraced, so you don't need to use "e => ". Also, instead of having "e" we now can use the @item object which represents the entity tied to our Grid. So, this leaves us with the following snippet of code (which will produce the end-result you're looking for):

```
            columns.Template(
                @<text>
                    @(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Action", "Controller", new { id = @item.ID }, new { @class = "standard button" }))
                </text>
            );
```

Comment: How to use if condition with item value inside column template ??